# VueJS 2.4 basic wrapper component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Maybe it's a simple question but I can't find the right way to create a basic wrapper component. For example I have a select like this:

```html
<select v-model="foo" name="bar" v-validate="'required'" v-bind:class="{ invalid: errors.has('bar') }">
    <option value="">Default</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

I need to add some sugar arround this, a `div` with the class `custom-select`. So I have created a `custom-select` component to wrap a native select:

```es6
Vue.component('custom-select', {
    template: `
        <div class="custom-select">
            <select v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$props">
                <slot></slot>
            </select>
        </div>
    `,
});
```

My issue is that my component doesn't inherit the props like `v-model` and `class`. I want to know if there is a global way, not to have to rewrite all the props in the component and let him inherit everything?

Comment: You might want to make your custom component take the select as a slot. In any case, `v-model` is not a prop and there is no straightforward way to proxy it down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-model` is just syntax sugar for `:value` and `@input`. It works differently for native input elements than it does for components; it's not as simple as just adding `v-on="$listeners" v-bind="$props"` to your component's template. It won't work.

If you want `v-model` to work, you'll need to handle the input event within the component and emit the changed value:

```html
<custom-select v-model="selected">
```

```es6
Vue.component('custom-select', {
  template: `
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select v-bind="$attrs" v-on="computedListeners">
        <slot></slot>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  computed: {
    computedListeners() {
      return Object.assign({}, this.$listeners, {
        input: e => this.$emit('input', e.target.value),
      });
    },
  },
});
```

The above is kind of a hack to make `v-model` work correctly, otherwise you could just do this:

```html
<custom-select :value="selected" @input="selected = $event.target.value">
```

```es6
Vue.component('custom-select', {
  template: `
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
        <slot></slot>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
});
```

Note that `class` and `style` cannot be proxied to the inner `<select>` because they're not props, they're handled specially by Vue and will be applied to the root element of the component's template.

EDIT: Actually you can proxy `class` and `style` but it requires writing the render function manually:

```es6
Vue.component('custom-select', {
  functional: true,
  render(h, ctx) {
    const on = Object.assign({}, ctx.listeners);
    if (ctx.listeners.input) {
      // Required for v-model to work
      on.input = e => ctx.listeners.input(e.target.value);
    }

    const data = Object.assign({}, ctx.data, { on });
    return h('div', { class: 'custom-select' }, [h('select', data, ctx.children)]);
  },
});
```

Comment: In your example how do you handle `v-bind:disabled=...` ? the component needs to have the disabled prop ? The point of my question not to have to write all this kind of bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer